# Xcode debugger static member variables

Tags: c++, xcode, gdb

Do you know how may I see the value of a static member variable from a class in xcode?
I can all the other variables except the static ones.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see Static Variable go to Globals in debugger.
under the library, select your project. To the right you should see your static variable. Tick the check box.

Now you can see the variable under Globals in debugger.

Cheers!

Comment: I didn't wait long enough to see them. You are right, but I have 114183 statics and it takes very long time to display them. Thanks!

Comment: Is this still valid?